# Vue.js + Element UI - How to get v-model array el-select

Tags: arrays, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm using el-select with v-model and options with different data. 
select use data `product.collection`
and for option select use data `options`

How do i can get v-model from render array product.collection?
like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRLON.png)

and this is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/dede402/9wp5ej8w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your JSFiddle, v-model is on `product.collection.name`, but `product.collection` is an array of objects. You should probably change to `product.collection` or specify an index like `product.collection[0].name`.

Take a look at code sample on http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select.

Here is a jsfiddle with a complete solution using an object as el-select value : https://jsfiddle.net/budgw/jsj9mnkx/1/

Notice the `value-key` attribute on `el-select`, this indicates the identity property. Also, the `product.collection` values must match the `option` values.

Comment: i've update my fiddle, but does''t happen with my code?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve by passing product.collection.name as a v-model. But here is an example that works and display the content of the v-model property : https://jsfiddle.net/budgw/jsj9mnkx/

Comment: thanks for your help,
so can you give me example how to create a method to change collection data to be selection data?
because collection data from server is array